# python3 openCV install error: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

Can anyone help me fixing an error when importing opencv in python3?

when I import cv2 in python3, I get something like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .cv2 import *

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): 
Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.55.78.100.dylib 
(which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.55.78.100.dylib
```

Also, I'm using python version 3.6.3

Comment: What kind of OS do you actually use?

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to upgrade your OS, you can install an earlier version of opencv:

`pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.10`

Comment: `ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==3.3.0.10`. But `3.4.5.20` still seems to work. Just avoid the `4.x` series.

Comment: For everyone else who tries a later 3.x version. I tried using `3.4.8.29` but that didn't work either (got the same error). `3.3.0.10` worked. @user124114

Answer (score 3):

clock_gettime() was added in macOS 10.12. It says so in the error message.

From what I understand it may be possible to build against an earlier Xcode SDK, but the easiest is probably to upgrade to Mac's latest OS.

Comment: Right. The easiest way to get a minor Python dependency to work is to upgrade the entire OS.