# conda error with openCV - symbol not found

Tags: python, opencv, conda, miniconda

I referred to the question:

[python3 openCV install error: Symbol not found: _clock_gettime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717726/python3-opencv-install-error-symbol-not-found-clock-gettime)

that suggest as answer to either upgrade the OS, either install a former version of openCV that does not call for _clock_gettime:

```
ImportError: dlopen([path]/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: [path]/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.22.100.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in [path]/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.22.100.dylib
```

I tried to install the downgraded version of opencv from a conda channel :

```
conda install -n mlvision -c rpi opencv
```

(see : https://anaconda.org/search?q=opencv)

The error persist when using jupyter, instead from the console it works fine.

I think the problem is in reference to the right environment.

I did the following:

conda create mlvision

```
conda activate mlvision

# install packages on local env
conda install -n mlvision keras
conda install -n mlvision -c rpi opencv
```

I see that in the error above the python path *does not point to the local conda environment*.

I created another question because the referenced answer above did not solve my issue.

__

NB using miniconda, not anaconda.
Mac OS 1.9.5

Answer (score -1):

You can try to install `opencv` from a different conda channel if you're not tied to `rpi`.

I would recommend going for [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) with `conda install -c conda-forge opencv`, or maybe default channels that should work with a simple `conda install opencv`.

Comment: I tried channel rpi because in another question opencv 3.3.0.10 was suggested to get rid of the symbol error. I still find symbol not found `_fdopendir$INODE64` error - see full:  `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Users/gg4u/Sites/miniconda3/envs/mlvision/bin/python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _fdopendir$INODE64
  Referenced from: /Users/gg4u/Sites/miniconda3/envs/mlvision/bin/python
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.`

Comment: Do you have this error with both conda-forge and main channels

Comment: Yes I also have symbol not found errors with conda-forge and main channels