# Installing opencv_python on MacOs 10.11.6

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to install opencv_python on python 3.7 and/or 3.8 on an old mac which I can only upgrade to to the current version 10.11.6.

When I try to run my script with

```
import cv2
```

in it I get this error:

> Error
>   ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user1/python/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): >Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
>    Referenced from: /Users/user1/python/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.31.100.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.13)
>    Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>    in /Users/user1/python/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.31.100.dylib

A number of references ([eg this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717726/python3-opencv-install-error-symbol-not-found-clock-gettime)) indicate that the version of open CV I need to use is 3.3.1.0 however when I try to install it with the command:

```
pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.10
```

as per the pypi instructions [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/3.3.0.10/) , I get this error.

> (3.8) NewMac:3.8 user1$  pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.10 ERROR:
>   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   opencv-python==3.3.0.10 (from versions: 3.4.2.16, 3.4.2.17, 3.4.3.18,
>   3.4.4.19, 3.4.5.20, 3.4.6.27, 3.4.7.28, 3.4.8.29, 3.4.9.31, 3.4.9.33, 4.0.0.21, 4.0.1.24, 4.1.0.25, 4.1.1.26, 4.1.2.30, 4.2.0.32, 4.2.0.34) ERROR: No matching distribution found for opencv-python==3.3.0.10

I wrote the python script a couple of years ago and it ran then under 3.7 so opencv ran then. Since then I have reinstalled opencv on the virtual environment I am running.

Any ideas where I can get an old opencv version? Unfortunately I can't afford a new computer at the moment.

Thanks for any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

That's weird, that specific version is listed in the pypi [website](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/3.3.0.10/#files).
Maybe you can manually download it from there and install it using:

```
pip install opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp27-cp27m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
```

Comment: I tried that with some of the cp3x-cp3xm wheels, but I it didn't work. I believe that cp27-cp27m refers to python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the [pypi page for opencv-python,](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/3.3.0.10/) you will find that they luckily still have the version you're looking for.
However, on the download page you will find that there is no 3.3.0.10 wheel file that supports Python 3.7 or 3.8.    You could install Python 3.6, which is the last supported version for that package.

Comment: Thanks for this - I think this is my next line of attack even though I don;t really want to do that, however I have never used 3.6 on this machine and the script definitely used to run. Would there be a dependency on the version of pip do you know? Thats the only thing I can think of...

Answer (score 0):

Okedoke. Thanks to both Mackaber and Max Crous for their answers. Both helped to get me where I need to be.

This morning I installed python 3.6, created and entered the venv and then tried a

```
pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.10
```

It failed. Then I downloaded the appropriate whl file from pypi and ran

```
pip install /Users/user1/Downloads/opencv_python-3.3.0.10-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl
```

which worked with no errors. I ran my script which also worked! (Yay!)

Postscript: The only explanation I have thought of for my failure to run the script before is that perhaps I was running the script outside of the venv and on python 3.7 and in fact it was using an older version of cvopen because of some environment variable not being set up correctly or something.

Answer (score 0):

1. you can install python=3.8.6
2. then run : pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.10

with no error it's work

Comment: Hi Muhammed. Thanks for your thoughts. I tried installing opencv with the pip install line that you suggested and got an error. Version of python I am using is 3.8.2 but I think the difference in the minor version number will not cause the error.

Comment: (In fact - I have just checked - latest version for Mac on python.org is 3.8.3 so I can't upgrade to 3.8.6 anyway)